# How to connect Blazor C# App to Azure SQL Database? MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, azure-sql-database, blazor-server-side

I am a beginner trying to get a Blazor C# App to connect to the SQL database I created on Azure.

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to connect these two on MacOS Visual Studio. I have found a few forums describing how it is done in windows but I can't seem to figure it out on mac. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The project examples in my answer have all been tried and run successfully, which can help you solve the problem. You should try it and hope to get your feedback. If there is any further need for help, I will be happy to help you.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Does my answer help you? I look forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read this [article](http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4318/Creating-A-Step-By-Step-End-To-End-Database-Server-Side-Blazor-Application.aspx), and follow the step to create a demo or download [`EndToEnd.sln`](http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/downloads/BlazorCookieAuthInsertDatabase.zip) to find out how to connect db on MAC OSX.

I have try it and success. My macOS Catalina version 10.15.5. There are some different in windows and mac by using visual studio. So I suggest you need to mirgration db first in windows. Then you can paste your db connections in your download project. Then you can see the website run successfully. You can do curd operations in this site. Good Luck !

If u need further help, pls let me know.

Comment: Linked article was not available when I tried it.

Comment: @codah https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/34